# Facing issue while trying to add cameraX dependency in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

I am making an Android app. While trying to add cameraX dependency to my app, I am facing "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)" in the highlighted line. My code:

```
    def camerax_version ="1.2.2"
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}")

    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}")
    implementation ("androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}")
```

I have no idea why I am getting the issue. Any solution or insight would be helpful.

Comment: Is the file named `build.gradle` or `build.gradle.kts`?

Comment: **https://developer.android.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started#**. try to follow official documentation and see if you might have missed any part of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: File name is build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 0):

Gradle files are written in either Groovy or Kotlin. You've mentioned in the comments that the file is named `build.gradle.kts`, i.e. it's written in Kotlin. Those written in Groovy are named `build.gradle`.

However, `def camerax_version ="1.2.2"` from the question follows Groovy syntax. Replacing it with `val camerax_version = "1.2.2"` should solve the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).